# How can I split String array with following delimiters in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a line in input file.
It is arranged as following (example):

```
(space)MOV(space)A,(space)(space)#20
```

When computer is reading this line, I plan to split() this string and add into the array. I use following code for this:

```
while((nline = bufreader.readLine()) != null)
{
    String[] array = nline.split("[ ,]");
```

With other words, string is splitted with delimiters: (space) and (comma). So, I expect my array to have a length of 3. but in practce I get 6.

So, as I understood, computer creates array of `{"(space)", "MOV", "(space)", "A", "(space)", "(space)", "#20"}`. However, I need this array: `{"MOV", "A", "#20"}`

How can I get this? Or how can I split the array according to the above mentioned delimiters. (I suppose that `nline.split("[ ,]")` is not correct).

Comment: I would use regex to grab the data directly.

Comment: It looks like there are multiple spaces between the commas.  You could split on `,` then `trim` each of the results to remove the extra leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @BeybarsMusagaliyev I edited my answer to make it cover all the expectations from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I put all the explanations in the comment to proper lines, have a look at this:

```
String nline;
BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("nameOfYourFile")));
while((nline = bufreader.readLine()) != null) {
    String trimmed = nline.trim(); // removing leading and trailing spaces
    // System.out.println(trimmed); Output from this line: >>MOV A,  #20<< (">>" and "<<" just to show where it begins and ends)
    String[] splitted = trimmed.split("[ |,]{1,}"); // split on ' ' OR ',' that appear AT LEAST once (so it also matches " ," (space + comma))
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted)); // Output: [MOV, A, #20]
}
bufreader.close();
```